# Python dictionary - value sublist

Tags: python

I have a dictionary.

I need to map the values to keys in such a way that each sub-list mapping should differ by 3.

The given dictionary is:

```
{
    8: [3, 4, 5, 6,9, 11, 12, 13, 14,15,17,18,19],
    15: [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20]
}
```

I need the values to be mapped to the keys in such a way below:

```
{
    8: [3,4,5,6,9],
    8_11: [11,12,13,14,15],
    8_17: [17,18,19],
    15: [4,5,6],
    15_10: [10,11,12,13,14],
    15_19: [19,20]
}
```

code already tried:

```
    for k,v in new_dic.items():
            for i in range(1,len(v)):
                if(v[i]-v[i-1]>1):
                    new_dic[k]=v[:i]
                    identity_switch[str(k)+'_'+str(v[i])]=v[i:]
```

Comment: Your question was as clear as a smoggy day in Beijing. I tried to clear it up a bit, but it's still a mess. It is not clear what the expected input is, nor what the desired output is.

Comment: Can you explain the logical rule you are trying to split your lists into?

Comment: There should be a difference of one with each consecutive element in a list. In the event that you find that there is a difference greater than one with consecutive items, create a new key value pair as mentioned above.

Comment: @SidharthSekhar Okay that's a useful explanation, but edit your question so that it reflects this explanation. Don't force people to trudge through the comments to understand the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to split your lists in a wrong way. Moreover, you are not updating your current dictionary properly. You could try the following script. Hope the `comments` are self-explanatory.

```
z = {
    8: [3, 4, 5, 6, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 17, 18, 19],
    15: [4, 5, 6, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 19, 20],
}

f = dict()  # Separating the cut off values which will be updated in the end
for key, value in z.items():
    value.sort()  # sorting the dictionary to get the difference properly
    l = [value[0]]
    x = value[0]
    check = True  # To check the initial cut off
    cut_off = 0  # To store initial cut off index
    for item in range(1, len(value)):
        if (value[item] - x) != 1:  # If difference is n.e 1
            if not check:  # If not first cut off updated over to be updated final dict
                f[str(key) + "_" + str(l[0])] = l
            x = value[item]
            l = [value[item]]
            if check:  # If first check store the index and turn first cut off check
                cut_off = item
                check = False
        else:
            x = value[item]
            l.append(value[item])

    if not check:  # Change the item to only accumulate diff of 1
        z[key] = value[0:cut_off]
    if l:  # If new list pending update into f
        f[str(key) + "_" + str(l[0])] = l

z.update(f)  # update original dictionary
print(z)
```

*Hope this solves your problem!!!*